# Floating point math going wrong using cpp_bin_float from boost::multiprecision

Tags: c++, boost, floating-point, arbitrary-precision

I tried the following:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp>

using float256 = boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_bin_float<192,
                  boost::multiprecision::backends::digit_base_2, void, long long int>, boost::multiprecision::et_off>;

void Test()
{
   double a = exp(-0.5);
   double b = boost::multiprecision::exp(float256(-0.5)).convert_to<double>();
   cout << a << endl << b << endl;
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. I am getting `0.606531` for `a` but `1` for `b`.

I'm running: boost 1.58, Linux, gcc 5.4.0.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: *Any idea what I am doing wrong?* -- Try a later version of boost.  You are 7 versions behind the current.

Comment: Well, that's the version from Ubuntu repositories. I will try a newer one. I didn't expect boost to contain such basic errors.

Comment: I have boost 1.62

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in boost. When the exponent template argument is a 64-bit integer type, the result of `exp` is rounded to an integer. This doesn't happen when `int` is used in place of `long long int`.

Edit: I have tracked the bug to the faulty implementation of `floor` and `ceil` functions. The offending line in both instances is:

```
if((arg.exponent() > (int)cpp_bin_float<Digits, DigitBase, Allocator, Exponent, MinE, MaxE>::max_exponent) || (shift <= 0))
//                    --- <=== !!!!
```

in `include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_bin_float.hpp`.

Comment: I tried Boost 1.65.1 and the problem persists. I reported the error, I will post a link if the bug is confirmed. Do you know if there is an arbitrary precision float library that is better unit-tested?

Comment: There ae many, but do you really need a 64 bit exponent? Do you plan to use numbers greater than 2^(2^30)?

Comment: Great! This is the issue: https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/13264
I think I can easily work with 32 bit exponents. But I makes a bad feeling if the very first think one tries with a new library immediately fails.